# Setting Headerdata (canonical) depending on magento pagetype

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to modify the page header depending on the page-type.
While canonicals on category and product pages are set manually, I want to fix pages, CMS-pages and blog-pages with a conditional.

The code I’m using now:

```
<?php
/*
Canonical Link snippet
Code by: Mohamed Elgharabawy [ItsCoding.com]
This will show the canonical links on CMS pages. You do not need this on catalogue and product pages as Magento has that function in place already
http://itscoding.com/how-to-add-rel-canonical-tag-to-magento
*/
// get the page type: CMS, Catalog, .. etc
$pageType = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
// if page type is cms or blog, put the canonical link
if ($pageType == "blog" || $pageType == "cms") 
 {
 $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
 $path = $url->getPath();
?>
<!-- Canonical link with (www) -->
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo "www.myDomain.com".$path; ?>" />
<?php
 }
?>
```

Works as expected on blog and CMS pages. 
However, as it comes to magento-standard-pages (/contacts), the canonical is not set. 
Which page type do I need to add to my statement in order to modify the header of (what I would call) standard pages?

Comment: Can't you test by echoing `$pageType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @TimCieplowski, that worked just fine. 
Im sorry that it took me almost 2 days to write a feedback.

The code Im using now 
(Update: forcing lowercase on canonical Domains)

```
   <!--canonical and href lang -->
<?php
/*
Canonical Link snippet
Code by: Mohamed Elgharabawy [ItsCoding.com]
This will show the canonical links on CMS pages. You do not need this on catalogue and product pages as Magento has that function in place already
http://itscoding.com/how-to-add-rel-canonical-tag-to-magento
*/
// get the page type: CMS, Catalog, .. etc
$pageType = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
// if page type is cms or blog, put the canonical link
if ($pageType != "catalog")
 {
 $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
 $path = $url->getPath();
 // your domain goes here 
 $canonical = "https://www.your-domain.com$path";
?>
<!--forcing lower case on canonical url - duplicate content and 404 prevention-->
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo strtolower ($canonical); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo strtolower ($canonical); ?>" hreflang="xx-XX" hreflang="x-default" />
<?php
 }
?>
<!--End canonical and href lang -->
```

Works as far as I can tell. In my case I need the canonical on all pages but product-related pages (type catalog). So it seems easier for me to test on !=catalog. 
The other way around would look like this:

```
if ($pageType != "catalog" || $pageType == "cms" || $pageType == "contacts")
```